# JS Arrays — Reorganize 1D Array into 2D Array of N Groups Placing Values Sequentially

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I've tried a few approaches to this but I can't seem to come up with a viable solution...

In short, I want to create a function to transform a 1D array of any length into a new 2D array of a specific length. Each value from the 1D array should be sequentially placed into each child-array up to the specified length, then start back at the first child-array.

Input / Desired Output Below:

```js
function groupArray(arr, numberOfGroups) {
 ...
};

// Input Data
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const size = 3;

console.log(groupArray(items, size));
// Expected Output
// [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) with index and wanted size of the array for getting the right target array.

```js
const
    groupArray = (array, size) => array.reduce((result, value, index) => {
        const target = index % size;
        if (!result[target]) result[target] = [];
        result[target].push(value);
        return result;
    }, []);

console.log(groupArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using nested `for`

```js
function groupArray(arr, numberOfGroups) {
  var result = []

  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; i++) {
    var subarr = []

    for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j += numberOfGroups) {
      subarr.push(arr[j])
    }

    result.push(subarr)
  }

  return result
};

// Input Data
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const size = 3;

console.log(groupArray(items, size));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also something like this would do it, 
you'd not need to mutate any input

```js
const chunkify = (step, list) => list.reduce(
  ([chunk, rest], item, i) => {
    const pick = i % step === 0;  

    return [
      chunk.concat(pick ? item : []),
      rest.concat(pick ? [] : item),
    ];
  },
  [[], []],
);

const group = (step, list, result = []) => {
  if (!list.length) { return result; }
  
  const [chunk, rest] = chunkify(step, list);
  
  return group(step - 1, rest, [...result, chunk]);
};

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const step = 3;

console.log(
  group(step, data),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have method `next`, each call will return next index and when limit reaches `numberOfGroups` reset the index 0. (in this case, it will be like 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2....)

With this method, can easily push to corresponding `output` sub array.

```js
const groupArray = (arr, numberOfGroups) => {
  const output = Array.from({ length: numberOfGroups }, () => []);
  const next = index => index % numberOfGroups;
  arr.forEach((num, i) => output[next(i)].push(num));
  return output;
};

// Input Data
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const size = 3;

console.log(groupArray(items, size));
```